# MaterialUI (MUI) BottomNavigation unwanted transparency

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

Aspiring hobby developer here. I've used create-react-app to start a new project and import the MUI dependencies.

I added a fixed BottomNavigation like this:

[image: Edit unwanted-transparant-bottomnavigation]

In CodeSandbox the BottomNavigation is not transparant as I would expect. However, on my development machine, the BottomNavigation is transparant. Meaning that when scrolling through longer pages, the content is visible through the BottomNavigation.

I have no idea what could be causing this? Could it be a bug in my MUI-version or should I check something in my code?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks for your time,

Maarten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not whether the [`BottomNavigation`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-bottom-navigation/) is transparent or not *(which is isn't)* -- the label on your [TextField](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/)s have a default [`zIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) value of `1` and your `BottomNavigation` does not have a `zIndex` defined at all.  This is making the label appear to "float above" the `BottomNavigation` in the current [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context). You can correct this by adding a `zIndex` of 1 (or higher) to the `sx` prop of `BottomNavigation`.  For example:

```
<BottomNavigation
  sx={{
    position: "fixed",
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    zIndex: 1 // Setting zIndex
  }}
>
```

FYI: The [`BottomNavigation` component API](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/bottom-navigation/#props) does **not** have an `elevation` prop. That's used by [Paper](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/paper/#props) for the drop shadow effect *(where I'm assuming you got your example)*.

**Working CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/unwanted-transparant-bottomnavigation-forked-cz97df

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you very much for such a detailed answer! Believe it or not, this has been bugging me for over a week... Adding the zIndex finally solved the problem!

Comment: Nice -- glad to help @Maarten!